# PO box validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, pattern-matching

I am trying to validate PO box with all the conditions satisfied in JavaScript But it is not working for me. its not matching any of the case

below is the reg expression that i used

```
function validatestreetAddress(street){
var streetval=street.value;
var pattern =new RegExp('/^ *((#\d+)|((box|bin)[-. \/\\]?\d+)|(.*p[ \.]? ?(o|0)[-. \/\\]? *-?((box|bin)|b|(#|num)?\d+))|(p(ost)? *(o(ff(ice)?)?)? *((box|bin)|b)? *\d+)|(p *-?\/?(o)? *-?box)|post office box|((box|bin)|b) *(number|num|#)? *\d+|(num|number|#) *\d+)/i');


 if (streetval.match(pattern)) { 
                    alert('We are unable to ship to a Post Office Box.\nPlease provide a different shipping address.'); 
}
```

only one reg exp works for me, but it is not satisfying all the conditions for PO box validation.

```
var pattern = new RegExp("\\b[P|p]*(OST|ost)*\\.*\\s*[O|o|0]*(ffice|FFICE)*\\.*\\s*[B|b][O|o|0][X|x]\\b");
```

could any one please suggest what is wrong in reg ex.

I want to match "Box 123", "Box-122", "Box122", "HC73 P.O. Box 217", "P O Box125", "P. O. Box", "P.O 123", "P.O. Box 123", "P.O. Box", "P.O.B 123", "P.O.B. 123", "P.O.B.", "POB 123", "POB", "POBOX123", "Po Box", "Post 123", "Post Box 123", "Post Office Box 123", "Post Office Box", "box #123", "box 122", "box 123", "number 123", "p box", "p-o box", post office box –  user3495160 3 hours ago

don't match = [ "The Postal Road", "Box Hill", "123 Some Street", "Controller's Office", "pollo St.", "123 box canyon rd", "777 Post Oak Blvd", "PSC 477 Box 396", "RR 1 Box 1020" ];

Comment: Give examples of what you want to match, and examples of ones that shouldn't match

Comment: I want to match  "Box 123", 
        "Box-122", 
        "Box122", 
        "HC73 P.O. Box 217", 
        "P O Box125", 
        "P. O. Box", 
        "P.O 123", 
        "P.O. Box 123", 
        "P.O. Box", 
        "P.O.B 123",
        "P.O.B. 123", 
        "P.O.B.",  
        "POB 123", 
        "POB", 
        "POBOX123",
        "Po Box", 
        "Post 123", 
        "Post Box 123", 
        "Post Office Box 123", 
        "Post Office Box", 
        "box #123", 
        "box 122", 
        "box 123", 
        "number 123", 
        "p box", 
        "p-o box", 
      post office box

Comment: don't match = [ 
        "The Postal Road", 
        "Box Hill", 
        "123 Some Street", 
        "Controller's Office", 
        "pollo St.", 
        "123 box canyon rd", 
        "777 Post Oak Blvd", 
        "PSC 477 Box 396", 
        "RR 1 Box 1020" 
        ];

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
("(post\s*(office)?)?\s*box\s*[#-]?\s*(\d+)?"|
"[\w\s]*?p(ost)?\s*[.-]?\s*o?\s*\.?\s*b?(ox)?\.?\s*(\d+)?"|
"\s*number\s*\d+")
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tG5aW4/5)